# How to bind object data with select option in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

Such the title, anyone can help me ? This is my code html

```
<select id="SelectTemplate">
        <option hidden disabled value>View available templates</option>
        <option *ngFor="let email of observableEmail | async">{{email.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Can you add object data and show us expected output?

Answer (score 0):

you are close, please refer Angular doc for examples, you can try:
('yourFunc' indicates your typescript method name)

```
<select id="SelectTemplate" (change) = "yourFunc($event.target.value)">
    <option hidden disabled value>View available templates</option>
    <option *ngFor="let email of observableEmail | async" [value]="email">{{email.name}}</option>
</select>
```